# How to select the value to check the account and password?

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt

I want to make a login window , and there are two QlineEdits in this window . We must input the correct account and password in it then login successful.
There are two groups account and password in member.db
First : Account:aaa , Password:000
Second : Account:bbb , Password:111

Here is part of my code: Howerver when I select the data of account , it can't catch the value .

```
 def buttonClicked(self):        
        model = QSqlQueryModel()
        a=model.setQuery("SELECT Password FROM member WHERE Account = values(\'{0}')".format(self.AccountEdit))
        if a==self.PasswordEdit.text():
            QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, 'message',"Congratulations !!!")
        else:
            QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'message',"Error !!!")
```

I think the error is in `a=model.setQuery("SELECT Password FROM member WHERE Account = values(\'{0}')".format(self.AccountEdit))` this code.
Because I tried to `print(a)` and it `return None` .

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid SQL; you should use just `WHERE Account = 'name'`.

Furthermore, to prevent [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, you should use parameters; this is possible only by using a separate `QSqlQuery` object:

```
query = QSqlQuery()
query.prepare("SELECT Password FROM member WHERE Account = ?")
query.bindValue(0, self.AccountEdit)
query.exec_()
model = QSqlQueryModel()
model.setQuery(query)
```